# sort by duplicated values and columns in a dataframe r

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data.frame looking like this

var  Freq

A   10

C   11

B    8

D    7

E    6

A    5

B    1

A    3

I need the output sorted on Freq first, if there is a duplicate in Var, the duplicates stay together, ranked by their highest Freq.

Var   Freq

C     11

A     10

A      5

A      3

B      8

B      1

D      7

E      6

Sorry about the format. Tried to sort on both columns, but couldn't move the duplicates together, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sort each group by their maximum and then by `Freq` in each group:

```
> dtt[order(-ave(dtt$Freq, dtt$var, FUN = max), -dtt$Freq), ]
#   var Freq
# 2   C   11
# 1   A   10
# 6   A    5
# 8   A    3
# 3   B    8
# 7   B    1
# 4   D    7
# 5   E    6
```

where `dtt` is:

```
> dput(dtt)
structure(list(var = c("A", "C", "B", "D", "E", "A", "B", "A"
), Freq = c(10L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("var", 
"Freq"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(var=c("A", "C", "B", "D", "E", "A", "B", "A"), 
                Freq=c(10,11,8,7,6,5,1,3))

varmax <- group_by(df, var) %>% summarise(gmax = max(Freq))

df <- left_join(df, varmax, by="var") 
df <- df[order(df$gmax, decreasing=TRUE),1:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using `Reduce()`:

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("A", "C", "B", "D", "E", "A", "B", "A"), 
             Freq = c(10, 11, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1, 3))
```

Split the dataframe into a list of data frames based on the var.
Order each of these dataframes by the Freq variable

```
df <- lapply(split(df, df$var), function(x) x[order(x$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),])

$A
  var Freq
1   A   10
6   A    5
8   A    3

$B
  var Freq
3   B    8
7   B    1

$C
  var Freq
2   C   11

$D
  var Freq
4   D    7

$E
  var Freq
5   E    6
```

Find the order of 'var'

```
df_order <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(df, function(x) x[x$Freq == max(x$Freq),]))
df_order <- df_order[order(df_order$Freq, decreasing = TRUE), 'var']

[1] C A B D E
```

sort the list based on this order

```
df <- df[df_order]
```

bring back to a data frame

```
df <- Reduce(rbind, df)
df

  var Freq
2   C   11
1   A   10
6   A    5
8   A    3
3   B    8
7   B    1
4   D    7
5   E    6
```